# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when creating DataFrame with ArrayType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create PySpark DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Test") \
    .master("local[4]") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType()), \
                     StructField('timestamp',LongType()), \
                     StructField('coordinates',ArrayType())])
rows = [Row(id="11", timestamp=1523975430000, coordinates = [41.5555, 2.1522])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```

However, I get the syntax error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` next to `lat`. I assume that `ArrayType` objects should be created differently.
Can someone help me creating this DataFrame `df`?

**Update:**

Expected result:

```
id    timestamp       coordinates
11    1523975430000    [41.5555, 2.1522]
```

Comment: You cannot make assignments inside of lists.

Comment: @timgeb: But there should be some way to save my data in DataFrame, no?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowledge how your dataframe is supposed to look like.

Comment: @timgeb: See my update where I show the expected DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayType needs type of elements. Try:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType()), \
                     StructField('timestamp',LongType()), \
                     StructField('coordinates',ArrayType(DoubleType()))])
rows = [Row(id="11", timestamp=1523975430000, coordinates = [ 41.5555,  2.1522])]
```

Results:

```
+---+-------------+-----------------+
| id|    timestamp|      coordinates|
+---+-------------+-----------------+
| 11|1523975430000|[41.5555, 2.1522]|
+---+-------------+-----------------+
```